# List of products in Schema.org

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

I read this [Google doc](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/products). It says we do not use the Product in list.

So for list of products (category of a similar products with multipage like 'shoes'), what kind of schema is recommended?

I use this:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebPage","name": "page name",
    "url": "http://www.example.com/shoes"
    "mainEntity":{
        "@type": "ItemList",
         "itemListElement":[{
             "@type": "BlogPosting"...
          }]
     }
     .
     .
     .
```

But `BlogPosting` for products seems is wrong.

Comment: Why *do* you use `BlogPosting`? And why not `Product`?

Comment: @unor because of this in the doc: `Use markup for a specific product, not a category or list of products.`

Comment: https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/5820005

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The linked documentation is for Google’s [Products rich result](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/products). It says that this specific rich result doesn’t support lists with different products. But this shouldn’t stop you from marking up such lists.

It is against [Google’s guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data#multiple-entities-on-the-same-page) to mark up only selected products in a list:

> A category page listing several different products (or recipes, videos, or any other type). Each entity should be marked up using the relevant schema.org type, such as [schema.org/Product](https://schema.org/Product) for product category pages. Marking up just one category entity from all listed on the page is against our guidelines.

Your JSON-LD example is a suitable way to mark up a list of products (replacing `BlogPosting` with `Product`, of course). But instead of `WebPage` you might want to use [`CollectionPage`](http://schema.org/CollectionPage).

Comment: Update: [`ProductCollection`](https://schema.org/ProductCollection) seems like a better fit; currently *proposed for full integration into Schema.org, [pending](https://schema.org/docs/pending.home.html) implementation feedback and adoption from applications and websites*

Comment: I'm looking at [`CollectionPage`](https://schema.org/CollectionPage) vs [`Collection`](https://schema.org/Collection) and I'm confused at what is the difference. The `Collection` at least has *e.g. creative works or products*, while the `CollectionPage` doesn't