# Schema.org for Category page

Tags: categories, schema.org, json-ld

Backstory: I'm working on e-commerce shop, we have category page displaying thumbnails of products, along with their prices, names, and short description. Can't buy from this page, need to enter product details page first.

I'm really confused about the usage of schema.org on category pages.

Came up with couple of solutions but can't tell which one's best (prefer the last one tbh)

1. `ItemList` with `ListItems` inside as recommended on https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings
   (Products are not supported, but it shows the idea behind placing several items on the site)

   ```
   {
   "@context": "http://schema.org",
   "@type": "ItemList",
   "name": "T-Shirt",
   "url": "/category/t-shirt/",
   "description": "Deserunt quibusdam ipsa illo ex nam ea illo qui. Itaque maiores doloribus accusamus ratione. Aperiam ipsa veritatis quas nisi.",
   "itemListOrder": "Unordered",
   "numberOfItems": 2,
   "itemListElement": [
       {
           "@type": "ListItem",
           "position": 1,
           "url": "/products/lopez-smith-25/?color=yellow&size=XXL",
           "name": "Yellow Lopez-Smith",
           "image": {
               "@context": "http://schema.org",
               "@type": "ImageObject",
               "contentUrl": "/media/__sized__/products/yellow_n2QjKzn-thumbnail-640x640-70.jpg",
               "description": "Lopez-Smith",
               "width": 640,
               "height": 640
           }
       },
       {
           "@type": "ListItem",
           "position": 2,
           "url": "/products/lopez-smith-25/?color=blue&size=37",
           "name": "Blue Lopez-Smith",
           "image": {
               "@context": "http://schema.org",
               "@type": "ImageObject",
               "contentUrl": "/media/__sized__/products/blue_FZ3yJjG-thumbnail-640x640-70.jpg",
               "description": "Lopez-Smith",
               "width": 640,
               "height": 640
           }
       }
   ]
   }
   ```

   2. Several Products as recommended on https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies
      Joined together using `@graph`

> A category page listing several different products (or recipes, videos, or any other type). Each entity should be marked up using the relevant schema.org type, such as schema.org/Product for product category pages. However, if one item is marked, all items should be marked. Also, unless this is a carousel page, the marked items should not link out to separate details pages.

```
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@graph": [
        {
            "@type": "Product",
            "@id": "/category/t-shirt/p-1",
            "description": "Nobis vel fugiat e",
            "name": "Yellow Lopez-Smith",
            "offers": {
                "@type": "Offer",
                "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
                "price": "18.28",
                "priceCurrency": "GBP",
                "itemCondition": "http://schema.org/NewCondition",
                "description": "Nobis vel fugiat e",
                "name": "Yellow Lopez-Smith",
                "gtin13": "68614",
                "category": "T-Shirt",
                "image": {
                    "@context": "http://schema.org",
                    "@type": "ImageObject",
                    "contentUrl": "/media/__sized__/products/yellow_n2QjKzn-thumbnail-640x640-70.jpg",
                    "description": "Lopez-Smith",
                    "width": 640,
                    "height": 640
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "@type": "Product",
            "@id": "/category/t-shirt/p-2",
            "description": "Nobis vel fugiat e",
            "name": "Blue Lopez-Smith",
            "offers": {
                "@type": "Offer",
                "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
                "price": "22.64",
                "priceCurrency": "GBP",
                "itemCondition": "http://schema.org/NewCondition",
                "description": "Nobis vel fugiat e",
                "name": "Blue Lopez-Smith",
                "gtin13": "73963",
                "category": "T-Shirt",
                "image": {
                    "@context": "http://schema.org",
                    "@type": "ImageObject",
                    "contentUrl": "/media/__sized__/products/blue_FZ3yJjG-thumbnail-640x640-70.jpg",
                    "description": "Lopez-Smith",
                    "width": 640,
                    "height": 640
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

3. Different `Products` listed as `ItemOffered` inside of `Offer` (based on Ebay)

   ```
   {
   "@context": "http://schema.org",
   "@type": "WebPageElement",
   "offers": {
       "@type": "Offer",
       "itemOffered": [
           {
               "@type": "Product",
               "@id": "/category/t-shirt/p-1",
               "description": "Nobis vel fugiat e",
               "name": "Yellow Lopez-Smith",
               "offers": {
                   "@type": "Offer",
                   "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
                   "price": "18.28",
                   "priceCurrency": "GBP",
                   "itemCondition": "http://schema.org/NewCondition",
                   "description": "Nobis vel fugiat e",
                   "name": "Yellow Lopez-Smith",
                   "gtin13": "68614",
                   "category": "T-Shirt",
                   "image": {
                       "@context": "http://schema.org",
                       "@type": "ImageObject",
                       "contentUrl": "/media/__sized__/products/yellow_n2QjKzn-thumbnail-640x640-70.jpg",
                       "description": "Lopez-Smith",
                       "width": 640,
                       "height": 640
                   }
               }
           },
           {
               "@type": "Product",
               "@id": "/category/t-shirt/p-2",
               "description": "Nobis vel fugiat e",
               "name": "Blue Lopez-Smith",
               "offers": {
                   "@type": "Offer",
                   "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
                   "price": "22.64",
                   "priceCurrency": "GBP",
                   "itemCondition": "http://schema.org/NewCondition",
                   "description": "Nobis vel fugiat e",
                   "name": "Blue Lopez-Smith",
                   "gtin13": "73963",
                   "category": "T-Shirt",
                   "image": {
                       "@context": "http://schema.org",
                       "@type": "ImageObject",
                       "contentUrl": "/media/__sized__/products/blue_FZ3yJjG-thumbnail-640x640-70.jpg",
                       "description": "Lopez-Smith",
                       "width": 640,
                       "height": 640
                   }
               }
               }
           ]
       }
   }
   ```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051841/list-of-products-in-schema-org